# React with Moment.duration: re-render component when duration reaches 0

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using moment.duration to build a countdown timer in a react.js app, pulling the original countdown time from an api call accessed in componentDidMount.

That much is working fine -- I would like, once my duration is 0 (once an event starts), to re-render the component (which will in turn pull a new time to serve as the countdown, as the json will be refreshed with Upcoming Events).

This seems like it should be easy with React, as I basically want to re-render the component every time I reach the duration, or when the countdown = 0.

Here's the render part of my code:

```
render: function() {
    UpcomingMenu = this.state.upcomingList || [];
    var currentTime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    // current system time in seconds
    console.log(currentTime);

     return (
        <div>
        <span>Upcoming LIVE Event: </span>
       {UpcomingMenu.map(function(el, i){

        if (el.eventStart > currentTime) {
          while (i < 1) { //i hate while loops. find a better way...
            var diffTime = el.eventStart - currentTime;
            var duration = moment.duration(diffTime*1000, 'milliseconds');
            var interval = 1000;
            if (typeof el.eventStart !== 'undefined') { //to prevent render twice error. i'm sure there's a better way around this.
              setInterval(function(){
                duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
                  $('.countdown').text(duration.days() + "d " + duration.hours() + "h " + duration.minutes() + "m " + duration.seconds() + "s")
              }, interval); 
            //re-render component?
            };

          var eventDetailsURL = decodeURIComponent(el.eventDetailsURL);
          var eventLiveURL = decodeURIComponent(el.eventLiveURL);
                 return <span key={i}>
                   <strong><a target="_blank" href={eventDetailsURL}>{el.eventTitle}</a></strong>
                    <p>
                    <span className="countdown"></span>                       
                    </p>

                </span>
            };

              };              
          })} 


          </div>           
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: when the duration is 0, refresh the state with more data. This will take care of the re-render.

Comment: @Vijay Thanks-- Yes, but duration is only being set at pageload right now.

Comment: @dilettante On reactjs main page there's a timer based example: https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html. If you haven't already, take a look at it. Essentially you want to do something like 'tick' function in there and keep setting the state (or resetting the state) appropriately, which will take care of re-rendering the component.

Comment: Thanks @KumarM. I ended up using the SetInterval function described on that page which mostly works great.

Answer (score 1):

it isn't a good practice to put setInterval inside your `render()` function. Render should be pure and has no side effect. You can always put your interval setup to another lifecycle method, eg. `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    eventStartTime: React.PropTypes.Date.isRequired
  };

  // every logic is here
  updateTimer = () => {
    // clean up previous timer
    clearTimeout(this.timer);

    const millisecondsAhead = this.props.eventStartTime - Date.now();
    const eventStarted = millisecondsAhead < 0;

    // calling setState will make your component re-render
    this.setState({
      eventStarted: eventStarted
    });

    if (!eventStarted) {
      this.timer = setTimeout(this.updateTimer, 1000);
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      eventStarted: false
    };

    this.updateTimer();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.eventStartTime !== this.props.eventStartTime) {
      this.updateTimer();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { eventStarted } = this.state;
    const millisecondsAhead = this.props.eventStartTime - Date.now();
    /*
     * render according to eventStarted and millisecondsAhead
     */
  }
}
```

Comment: Better to use setInterval instead of setTimeout. maybe, another method called initTimer to do cleanup actions and start the timer.

Comment: @tungv as a good practice you'd want to have the constructor as the first thing in your class. It just gets confusing otherwise.

Comment: Hello, setInterval mostly worked, and I moved the constructor earlier in the class definition. Thanks to you both.